# Why is plain jar file compressed to 76% but after ProGuard shrink & obfuscate; it is compressed to 102% ?! How to fix?

Tags: windows-7, compression, zip, 7-zip, jar

I have a jar file of size 392 MB. I made another copy of it, so I have now two copies of the same jar file.

For one of them I used [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to compress it. It is compressed to 76% of the original size, that is 298 MB

For the other one; I first used [proGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to shrink and obfuscate it. After shrinking it, its size went down to 348 MB. After that I compressed it with 7-zip. It is compressed to **102%** of the shrunk size that is 355 MB!!!

What is wrong?
How to fix?

Comment: Compassion is based on the data, if isn't designed to be compressed (video,audio, obfuscation) this happens, nothing is wrong, it's working as intended

Comment: @Ramhound ; both are the same jar, but one has extra step of (shrink & obfuscate) - this doesn't change the formate. It is still a jar formate - What troubles me is that it is not compressed down as the non-shrunk non-obfuscated one!! - OK then I just rather have to send the uncompressed jar.

Comment: Right; the obfuscation is to blame;

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound, this is not the same file anymore... it has been changed, cleaned and obfuscated, it is different data than the original file, there is no guarantee it will compress the same as the original file, it is different now.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to be able to compress a file with one application, then take that output and compress it again, and take that output and compress it again, etc., until the file is only 1 byte? Compression and encryption both aim to make the resulting data random, and you can only get so random. At some point, you are just rearranging the chaos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing function names with near random names, then changing the calling patterns for the functions and pre-compressing the file ("shrinking") you are effectively removing all the repetitive blocks that a compression algorithm can see and use to compress the file further.

With no repetitive blocks in the data stream there is nothing a compression algorithm can do to remove duplicate blocks, but the reason you are seeing an increase in file size is because the compression method has its own overheads it puts into an output file. The compressor will have a dictionary of "phrases" that are duplicated within the file and then the compressed file essentially is a list of lookups to that dictionary, but with no duplicates in the file the dictionary becomes a copy of the original file and the lookups are still there with each one pointing to only one item in the dictionary.

What this means is that for an already compressed file there is no way that the output file can be smaller than the original file.  You will always end up storing what is essentially the entire file along with a lookup table telling the decompression algorithm how to rebuild the original file.